# How do I check the type of an error?

Tags: go

I want to check the error type from a function I call to see if it was caused by a deadlineExceededError but I don't see a way to reference it. I suppose I can always check against the `.Error()` string but I've been told that's frowned upon.

Also it's set to 2 microseconds for debugging purposes, I realize it should be changed to `time.Minute`

Godoc for the function in question: https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client#Client.ContainerStart

```golang
//if the container fails to start after 2 minutes then we should timeout
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 2*time.Microsecond)

defer cancel()
// Do the actual start
if err := myClient.ContainerStart(ctx, containerName, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err) //prints: 'context deadline exceeded'
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", err) //prints: 'context.deadlineExceededError'
    switch e := err.(type) {
    case //how do I check for deadlineExceededError:
         //print that it timed out here
    }
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [context package exposes this value as a variable](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#pkg-variables).

You can compare `err == context.DeadlineExceeded`.

However, as [argued by Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully), you should probably use an interface instead.

Specifically [`net.Error`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error) or `interface { Timeout() bool }` will work as a type.